# Lazy loading and fullpage jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, load, lazy-evaluation, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js but I got 20 images to show. With a slow connection this take a long time to load.

So I would like to load normally the first four images normally and the others images with a lazy load system. I saw in the docs to run the lazy load function we must add `data-src` in the img tag.

So I had data-src after the fith images...

```
<div class="slide slide0">
<img src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide1">
<img src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide2">
<img src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide3">
<img src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide4">
<img data-src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide5">
<img data-src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="slide slide6">
<img data-src="url-of-the-image.jpg">
</div>
```

But the problem is that from the fifth image each image are load when they are in the viewport. We got the time to see the image to load...

Example of lazy load function : https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/eNLBXo

Do you have an idea to load from the fifth image each image one by one before to be in the viewport ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of lazy loading, only loading images when the user is about to see them. In this case, they are loaded on the `onLeave` callback when we know the user is going to end up in that certain section or slide.

If you just want to load them on page load, do not add the `data-src` and load them normally.

If for some strange reason you just want to delay the load you can always use a `setTimeout` within the `afterRender` callback, but I don't see the point on it.